# How to suppress loop in go.Sankey?

Tags: plotly, plotly-python

I am a beginner in Plotly and use this library for drawing Sankey diagrams. Here is my script (not exactly the same, but quite similar):

```html
import plotly.graph_objects as go

fig = go.Figure(go.Sankey(
    arrangement = "snap",
    node = {
        "label": ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"],
        "x": [0.2, 0.1, 0.5, 0.7, 0.3, 0.5],
        "y": [0.7, 0.5, 0.2, 0.4, 0.2, 0.3],
        'pad':10},  # 10 Pixels
    link = {
        "source": [0, 0, 1, 2, 5, 4, 3, 5],
        "target": [5, 3, 4, 3, 0, 2, 2, 3],
        "value": [1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2]}))

fig.show()
```

And my Sankey looks like below:
[image]

My question is, how to suppress the loops in the plotting? I want something similar to the one below even if there are duplicate labels among columns:
[image]

Is that supported?